# How to retrieve datewise data from API in Android?

Tags: java, api, rest, android-studio, retrofit2

Here's the link to the API:
https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/historical/all?lastdays=all

So as you can see in the above API there are three keys cases, deaths & recovered.
And I want to retrieve the all the data under these keys but the problem is data under these keys is in "**date format**". So I am confused in making the model classes of these 3 keys. Can anyone suggest how should I approach in making model classes and retrieve data? I am using Retrofit Library to fetch data from API in android.